# How to "reconnect" an ORM object or list of such objects with the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My understanding is that the following code will return an error:

```
from src.mysqlClient import db_session
from src.mysqlClient.models import AdvertDom

with db_session() as session:
    advert_doms = session.query(AdvertDom).all()

for advert_dom in advert_doms:
    print(advert_dom.HTMLContent)
```

My understanding is that the error is caused by the session ending, which disconnects the `advert_doms` list from the database.

---

If I have a function that returns an ORM object or list of ORM objects, how can I have the objects later "reconnect" with the database so that the code above would work?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
from src.mysqlClient import db_session
from src.mysqlClient.models import AdvertDom

def function_one():
    with db_session() as session:
        advert_doms = session.query(AdvertDom).all()
    return advert_doms

def function_two()
    advert_doms = function_one()

    # TODO: Do something here so that the code below will work.

    for advert_dom in advert_doms:
        print(advert_dom.HTMLContent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a new session and do `session.add(orm_object)`:

```
from src.mysqlClient import db_session
from src.mysqlClient.models import AdvertDom

def function_one():
    with db_session() as session:
        advert_doms = session.query(AdvertDom).all()
    return advert_doms

def function_two()
    advert_doms = function_one()
    with db_session() as session:  # <-- New line of code
        for advert_dom in advert_doms:
            session.add(advert_dom)  # <-- New line of code
            print(advert_dom.HTMLContent)
```

---

The other way to avoid this problem is to just have a single global session object that doesn't get closed until both functions have run.